# React google oauth signin getting false on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, google-api-js-client

I want to keep my user on a page whenever he is logged in. However, If I refresh the page I get false (user is not logged in) whereas if I write the same code on chrome's console dev tools I get true (the user is logged in).

Component.jsx

```js
import React from "react";

const isSignedIn = ()=> !!(window.gapi && window.gapi.auth2 && window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(isSignedIn());
  console.log("isLoggedIn ", isLoggedIn);
  
  return (
    isLoggedIn ? <div> User is logged in </div> : <div> User is NOT logged in </div>
  );
}
```

Chrome's console code:

```js
const isSignedIn = ()=> !!(window.gapi && window.gapi.auth2 && window.gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());


isSignedIn();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the credentials in something like session storage or cookies to not lost it.